# Can't ssh or console to the guest using ubuntu-vm-builder

Tags: 11.10, kvm-virtualization

I'm running Oneric as the host, would like to create several virtual machines. Both the host and the guests will be headless - there is no display connected, and I'd like to connect to them via ssh.

Looks like kvm is the official ubuntu recommended way, so I'm following the documentation: http://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests

Here's my ubuntu-vm-builder command:

```
sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm oneiric \
              --domain xpstage --dest xpstage --hostname xpstage \
              --arch i386 --mem 1024 \
              --user myusername --pass mypassword \
              --bridge virbr0 --ip 192.168.122.2 --dns 8.8.8.8 \
              --components main,universe,restricted \
              --addpkg acpid --addpkg vim --addpkg openssh-server --addpkg avahi-daemon \
              --libvirt qemu:///system ;
```

The guest appears to build just fine, but I can't reach it.

```
ssh myusername@192.168.122.2
```

times out. My bridge network is setup:

```
virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:673 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:60839 (60.8 KB)  TX bytes:882 (882.0 B)
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there.

Having failed with ssh I tried to console into it, but

```
virsh console xpstage
```

returns immediately, so I added a [pty section to the configuration](http://bsdjlh.blogspot.com/2010/06/debian-kvm-console-on-headless-server.html):

```
virsh edit xpstage
```

After adding the pty `virsh console xpstage` connects, but doesn't display anything and key presses don't do anything.

I then tried setting up a [Serial Console](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto), but upstart doesn't like that: `start: Unknown job: ttyS0` .

Can some kind soul please guide me to how to setup a headless KVM guest on Oneric that I can connect to?

Comment: Hi Parand, I came here to find or ask this same question (except my host is Oneiric Desktop, guests are Oneiric server).  Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Though I still need to learn to do it via console, If you have a Workstation I would suggest installing virt-manager and connecting it to you KVM server and installing your guest through it, This is what i did and it was near painless, you will need the ISO of whichever your trying to install on the Server.

I did this on a Intel Dual core 2.0ghz with 4gb ram

To this day that VM is running my Website

Comment: I did it your way, and have the same problem as Parand.  There's something in default configuration of Oneiric Server running as a guest that seems to block incoming requests, even to *sshd -D* running on open port 22.

Comment: That is interesting, While going through the install process I set up as usual and made sure to select SSH server when it asks what services to install, WAIT as per the WIKI https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking#Creating_a_network_bridge_on_the_host I also created a bridge labeled br0 exactly as the guide supplies, except changing the Addresses where needed give this a shot would be my next suggestion, as if its still running in the virt networking it will have a strange IP either way on the VM try running ifconfig and pulling the IP @Kurtosis